# Importing fastai in GoogleColab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am trying to import this module in googlecolab for my code. As I want to run my code with GPU but even when I do `pip install fastai` or `pip3 intall fastai` , it says requirement satisfied but gives me error when I run these:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
import gc 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.vision.all'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade fastai. Run the following instead:

```sh
!pip install fastai --upgrade
```

Then, check if the installed version is 2.0 or higher:

```py
import fastai

print(fastai.__version__)
```